# How to change price on button pressed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

> SCENARIO

I have a dummy image, under image there is price and under price there three widget
Two widget are buttons (+) and (-) and one widget is Text('1') which is a QTY.

> QUESTION

When i click on the button it increment and decrement the number but how do i change the price based on QTY (if QTY is 2 then price must be double)

```
    class Quantities extends StatefulWidget {
      final productprice;
      final productimage;
      Quantities({this.productprice, this.productimage});
      @override
      _QuantitiesState createState() => _QuantitiesState(productprice,productimage);
    }
    class _QuantitiesState extends State<Quantities> {
      int counter = 1;
  final productprice;
  final productimage;
  _QuantitiesState(this.productprice, this.productimage);
      void increment() {
        setState(() {
          counter++;
        });
      }
      void decrement() {
        setState(() {
          counter--;
        });
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return PlatformScaffold(
          appBar: PlatformAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[900],
            title: Text('Quantities'),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: GridTile(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Image.asset(productimage),),),),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    productprice,),),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                        child: PlatformButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              decrement();
                              if (counter < 1) {
                                counter = 1;
                              }
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              '-',
                            ),
                            androidFlat: (_) =>
                                MaterialFlatButtonData(color: Colors.cyan),
                            ios: (_) => CupertinoButtonData(
                                color: Colors.cyan
                            )),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '$counter',
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                        child: PlatformButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              increment();
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              '+',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0),
                            ),
                            androidFlat: (_) =>
                                MaterialFlatButtonData(color: Colors.cyan),
                            ios: (_) => CupertinoButtonData(
                                color: Colors.cyan
                            )),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the full code example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_app/proyects/home.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Product price',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Quantities(productimage: "",productprice: "20$",),
    );
  }
}

class Quantities extends StatefulWidget {
  final productprice;
  final productimage;
  Quantities({this.productprice, this.productimage});
  @override
  _QuantitiesState createState() =>
      _QuantitiesState(productprice, productimage);
}

class _QuantitiesState extends State<Quantities> {
  int counter = 1;
  final productprice;
  double finalprice;
  final productimage;
  final productp =productprice.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\$'), '');
  _QuantitiesState(this.productprice, this.productimage);
  void increment() {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
      finalprice=double.parse(productp)*counter;
    });
  }

  void decrement() {
    setState(() {
      counter--;
      finalprice=double.parse(productp)*counter;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    finalprice= double.parse(productp);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[900],
          title: Text('Quantities'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  finalprice.toString(),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                        child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (counter > 1) {
                              decrement();
                            }
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            '-',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '$counter',
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                        child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            increment();
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            '+',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: @GonzaG You have already pass the price value `home: Quantities(productprice: 180.0,)` .In my case i did `Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>Quantities(productprice: widget.productdetailprice,)));` in the previous page and passed this productprice in TextWidget in Quantities Page .The productprice(20$) is in JSON.

Comment: u need to transform "20$" to a double.   `final priceofproduct =productprice.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\$'), '');
        double pricedouble = double.parse(priceofproduct);`

Comment: How do i convert the double to string because in the Text widget if i type `finalprice.toString()` then it shows an error of type string is not a subtype of type double.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to multiply the value of product price in

`setstate(){
   productprice=productprice*counter;
}`

or

```
productprice*=counter;
```

Comment: Do i need to create a new function?

Comment: if productprice is a number you only need to do this:  `void increment() {
   setState(() {
      counter++;
      productprice*=counter;
    });
  }
  void decrement() {
    setState(() {
      counter--;
      productprice*=counter;
    });
  }`

Comment: What about in Text Widget `Text(
                "Price: "+widget.productprice)`

Comment: can be changed to this `Text( "Price: "+widget.productprice.toString())`

Comment: It is not working instead it is showing "20$20$" after clicking increment button